# How to pipe the output of a command to file on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am running a task on the CLI, which prompts me for a yes/no input.

After selecting a choice, a large amount of info scrolls by on the screen - including several errors. I want to pipe this output to a file so I can see the errors. A simple '>' is not working since the command expects keyboard input.

I am running on Ubuntu 9.1.

Comment: What is the name of the command are you running? make?

Answer (score 50):

```
command &> output.txt
```

You can use `&>` to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file. This is shorthand for `command > output.txt 2>&1` where the `2>&1` means "send stderr to the same place as stdout" (stdout is file descriptor 1, stderr is 2).

For interactive commands I usually don't bother saving to a file if I can use `less` and read the results right away:

```
command 2>&1 | less
```

Comment: Redirecting both stdout and stderr to a file means he wont see the actual prompt. I can't see how he would be any better off than the situation he describes in his question.

Comment: You used `&` at both side of the numbers (`1`, `2`). Is using `&2` or `2&`, even  `2&>1` or `2>&1` makes any difference?

Comment: @FredrickGauss Oops! I had a typo in my answer. `2&>1` is not valid. I meant to write `2>&1`.

Comment: When the question arises: what is the meaining of `&` sign with a number after it (i.e. 2>&1) and without a number (you say without a number is both stdout and stderr, right)?

Comment: (1) If you write `>2` then bash will write to a file named `2`. Writing `>&2` tells bash that `2` is a file descriptor number instead of a file name. (2) Writing a number *before* the `>` does not require `&`, since a file name is never valid on the left. (3) `&>` is a special syntax for redirecting both stdout and stderr. It can also be written as `>&`, though `&>` is preferred. Both of these are special syntax. Don't try to figure out what the `>` and `&` mean on their own. Think of `&>` as a single operator.

Comment: Put (1) and (2) together and you get `2>&1`.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo yes | command > output.txt
```

Depending on how the command reads it's input (some programs discard whatever was on stdin before it displays it's prompt, but most don't), this should work on any sane CLI-environment.

Comment: I think you mean `echo yes | command` rather than `command < \`echo yes\``. (There's also the `yes` command which might be useful.)

Comment: You're right. I started out thinking he could put his input in a file, and changed my mind to simply using echo instead, but forgot to change the command-line to match. Fixed it now.

Comment: This reformats the json I wanted to write a file unfortunately.

Comment: @metanerd: Pipes and redirects don't make any changes to the bytes that pass through them, so if your json is reformatted, that is because one of the involved commands does it. Some commands change their behavior when they detect that their output is piped/redirected, which could explain what you see.

Answer (score 1):

Use `2>` rather than just `>`.

Answer (score 1):

If the program was written by a sane person what you probably want is the stderr not the stdout. You would achieve this by using something like

`foo 2> errors.txt`

Answer (score 1):

you can use 2> option to send errors to the file.

example:

command 2> error.txt

(use of option 2>) --- see if their would be any error while the execution of the command it will send it to the file error.txt.